# Идентификация пользователя на стороне сервера средстави PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какими способами можно идентифицировать пользователя на стороне сервера средствами PHP?

Задача состоит в том, что нужно опознать пользователя, который загружает картинки на сервер(плагин jquery file upload). Сервер, получая эти файлы загружает во временную таблицу названия файлов и  идентификатор пользователя(чтобы при следующем посещении эти файлы для пользователя достать).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может являться этим идентификатором?

Думаю, что для пользователя можно сделать рандомное число и присвоить через куки как id пользователя.

Также обнаружил в $_COOKIE ключ с PHPSESSID. Можно ли исползовать это значение?

Либо я неправильно думаю и есть другие способы как это делается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает.

Спасибо!

Comment: Раз зарегистрированные пользователи грузят картинки, то куки от них передаются, и PHPSESSID передается. Соответственно вы можете использовать стандартную аутентификацию пользователей вашего сайта в файле приема картинок, такую же как на других страницах сайта.

Comment: @Visman А если пользователи пользователь не зраегистрирован, то как лучше сделать?

Comment: А у вас незарегистрированный конкретный гость на сайте как-то идентифицируются? Через те же сессии? Если да, то все то же самое: стандартная система аутентификации как на основном сайте. Если нет, то лучше, наверное, городить огород просто с куками, но не с сессиями, сессии на гостях вам могут и временную директорию забить на сервере, и базу, если сессии в базе храните. Значение куки генерировать лучше подлиннее, с проверкой подлинности, чтобы подобрать простым перебором было сложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPSESSID даже в кукисах лучше не трогать.

Простое решение:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']))
{
    $folder = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
}
else
{
   // md5 можно заменить на sha1
   // 'соль' НУЖНО заменить на секретное слово. Своё.
   $folder = md5('соль' + rand());
   // Сохраняем кукис надолго
   setcookie('user_id', $folder, strtotime('+5 year'));
}

echo is_dir($folder); // Начинаем использовать
```