# Что можно взять с устройства, кроме IP?

Tags: php, ip

Я пишу сайт на php и у меня такая проблема: при добавлении товара в корзину, я считываю ip устройства. И если я с компьютера и телефона, которые подключены к одному WiFi, добавляю товар, ip у них одинаковый. 
Что можно использовать, чтобы устройства, подключенные к одному WiFi, были различны?

Comment: почти в тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575852/178576

Comment: ещё более в тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739684/178576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не совсем корректный подход.
Для идентификации пользователя вам необходимо использовать [session_id](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-id.php), а не IP

Когда разберетесь с этим и начнете работу над авторизацией/регистрацией, обязательно ознакомьтесь с тем, что такое [куки](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

Comment: Мне кажется, если учить по такой схеме, логично начать с ознакомления cookie, так как сессии работают именно через этот механизм? Поправьте, если ошибаюсь, я не программист PHP

Comment: @МаксимЛевицкий, других [механизмов управления состояниями](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265), помимо cookies, протокол http не предусматривает.